# Как закруглить углы у блока?

Tags: html, css

Решил сделать на странице блок с закруглёными углами, но в интернете ничего путного по этому вопросу нет, подскажите кто чем может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) (css-свойство), но это не работает в IE8 и раньше. Если это не проблема, то используем border-radius, если иначе, то есть один корявый способ решить эту проблему для IE, либо вручную делать с помощью картинок, как это сделано на странице по ссылке.

И да, [вот качественное кросс-браузерное решение](http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/) без использования таких тяжёлых средств, как рисование руками. С [демкой](http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius-demo.zip).

Answer (score 1):

[38 статей о создании закругленных углов на сайтах](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/30019/) - посмотрите, может подойдет.

Answer (score -1):

А можно только углы сверху скруглить:

```
#block {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #CCC;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
```